# C++ count_if function - couldn't infer template

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use C++'s `count_if` function to see how many hex digits are in a `std::string`. When I try the following:

```
string s = "123abc";
cout << count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isxdigit) << endl;
```

I get the following error:

```
count.cpp:14:13: error: no matching function for call to 'count_if'
    cout << count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isxdigit) << endl;
            ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h:448:5: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer
  template argument '_Predicate'
count_if(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
```

However, when I use `::isxdigit`, the program compiles and runs. I know prepending the `::` has something to do with using the `isxdigit` in the global scope, but I'm not sure why it helps in this case.  I also think it has something to do with C++ locales, but I'm not too familiar with them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a function `int isxdigit(int)` in the C Standard Library (header `<ctype.h>`, C++ equivalent header `<cctype>`). This can be used unambiguously in `count_if`.

If you include `<ctype.h>`, this function ends up in the global namespace. If you include `<cctype>`, it's guaranteed to be put in namespace `std`; but as it's a C-library function, your C++ Standard Library (implementation) is allowed to put it into the global namespace as well.

On the other hand, there is a function *template* `isxdigit` in the C++ Standard Library (header `<locale>`). This is only put into namespace `std`.

---

The reason why you get this error is because you probably have a `using namespace std;` somewhere, or otherwise make `std::isxdigit` from `<locale>` visible. Then, the name `isxdigit` refers to a set of overloaded functions. As there are multiple candidates, and `count_if` accepts many of them, the compiler cannot now which overload you meant.

You can specify which overload was meant, for example, by using `static_cast<int(*)(int)>(&isxdigit)`.

---

When you use `::isxdigit`, only one function is found, so the compiler knows its type and can deduce the template parameter.

---

A more useful solution than manually choosing the overload is to use a function object with a generic function call operator:

```
struct Isxdigit
{
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T const& p) const
    {
        using std::isxdigit;
        return isxdigit(p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    string s = "123abc";
    cout << count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), Isxdigit()) << endl;
}
```

This automatically selects the proper overload.

In C++1y, you could use generic lambdas:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "123abc";
    cout << count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](auto p){ return isxdigit(p); })
         << endl;
}
```